# Android app for auto pasting text?

Tags: android, clipboard

I am look for a app for auto pasting text when there is change in clipboard. The use case is that I have the android in sync with my laptop's clipboard, so when I write something on my laptop (usually in vim), it will be available in android immediately. But I still have to long tap the android device and select paste, and this interrupts the workflow. I am wondering if there is an app to solve this problem.

(BTW, the app I am using for syncing clipboards is called [Clipbrd](http://www.appbrain.com/app/clipbrd-beta/com.clipbrd).)

The auto-paste should work as a service which I can toggle on when needed (and off when done), so it auto-pastes content to any app running in the foreground whenever new clipboard content is received while it's "turned on" – and doesn't interfere with whatever I'm doing when it's "turned off".

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly address your requirement, but offeres a better-than-nothing workaround:

You can use [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard). If you configure "Keyboard mode" to `full 5-row layout` and "Ctrl key code" to `Left Ctrl`, then you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> shortcut to paste just like you do on a computer. The difference is that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is sticky. So you can paste the clipboard in two taps or just one quick swipe from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>v</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Wow – didn't know that HK could do that. It's no auto-paste as the OP wished for, but a single "swipe" is definitely an improvement to his situation, too!

Comment: @Izzy Right, it's not a direct answer. I wasn't sure if it would be better off as an answer or a comment, but maybe more people will see it here

Comment: Perfectly fine to me (I already upvoted it)! Not sure if some auto-paste is available at all. And if so, it might be "disturbing" sometimes. Let's ask the OP for some more specifics.